# Create a flutter app that has a native appearance

Tags: flutter, flutter-native, flutter-native-view

I want to create a flutter application that has a native appearance on iOS if I compile for iOS, macOs and a native appearance on Android for the rest of the platforms.

I am using flutter 3.16

Is this possible without duplicating code?